# my searchbar is expanding in landscape mode in simulator but not on device Iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

On simulator when I switch from portrait to landscape in Tableview my searchbar expands.
but on device it is not expanding.

Any Idea I am very upset due to that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to guess what the issue might be. Have you set the autoresizingMask on your search bar? I'm guessing you'll want it to expand width-wise, so you'll want autoresizingMask set to something like UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth.